# 0403-012 A test command parameter is not valid

Tags: shell

Issue with braces which is used in if statement.

```
fileResult=`rsh $nsmHost "find $keyPackagePath -name '*.pgp' -exec ls -ltr '{}' +" | awk '{print $9}' | sort -k1.32`

for i in $fileResult
  do
    #Extract Minor Version and Major version
    keyMajVersion=`echo $i|cut -d '.' -f2 | cut -c19-`
    keyMinVersion=`echo $i|cut -d '.' -f3 | cut -d '_' -f1`

    if [ -f $versionFile ]
    then
      majVersion=`cat $versionFile|cut -d '.' -f1`
      minVersion=`cat $versionFile|cut -d '.' -f2`

      if [ [ $keyMajVersion == `echo "$majVersion + 1" | bc` ] && [ $keyMinVersion = `echo "$minVersion + 1" | bc` ] ] || [ [ $keyMajVersion = $majVersion ] && [ $keyMinVersion" = `echo
 "$minVersion + 1" | bc` ] ]
      then
        #install and Activate
        #triggerPollNDeploy
        echo "KUM::Version file exist and support next package deploy"
        #Update version in VersionFile and break
        echo "$keyMajVersion.$keyMinVersion" > $versionFile
       fi
```

Comment: if [ [ $keyMajVersion == `echo "$majVersion + 1" | bc` ] && [ $keyMinVersion == `echo "${minVersion} + 1" | bc` ] ] || [ [ $keyMajVersion == $majVersion ] && [ $keyMinVersion == `echo "$minVersion + 1"
 | bc` ] ]

Comment: above one is the proper if condiiton i tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Be sure to include the expected result, and the actual result.  Also, make sure you ask a question.  I'm not quite sure what you are requesting help with.

Comment: Run your shell via https://www.shellcheck.net/ ... [Don't parse ls output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). [Quotes!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). And backticks \` are [deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) and `$( ...)` is preferred. Also the `[ [ ` is invalid, the `[` command can't parse `[`. Why not just `[ that = this -a that = this ]`. Also note that `==` is invalid, `=` is the proper string comparision. Do you use POSIX shell or have bash? What is your shebang?